# get last 3 months on date selection

Tags: sql-server, date, datepicker

I have datepicker on form.aspx fromdate & to date i want when i select date from date picker then i want last 3 month record on the basic of datepicker selection i.e. if i select date from DEC then last 3 month record display

i try this

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPMONTH]
@fromdate datetime,
@todate datetime
AS

select DATENAME(MONTH,tblReg.StartDate) AS [Month]
from tblReg
where
tblReg.StartDate>=DATEADD(MONTH,-3,GETDATE())
AND tblReg.EndDate<=GETDATE()
GROUP BY 
DATENAME(MONTH,tblReg.StartDate)
```

when i execute this

```
[SPMONTH] '2016-01-01 00:00:00', '2016-01-30 23:59:59'
```

result

```
Month
August
July
June
May
```

above sp works but when i select date from aug then this show last 3 months and current month whereas when i select date from jan or another month then this  shows july,june and may data whereas i want when i select jan or any other month suppose i select jan then want dec,nov,oct and jan

Comment: you aren't passing the date into the SQL. Unless "@RegNo" is supposed to hold the date (in which case it needs a better name!). But even then @RegNo is never used within the procedure itself. So how can you expect it to dynamically adjust to the value you selected if you aren't passing that value into your code?

Comment: @ADyson check update

Comment: You got 2 variables (`@fromdate`,`@todate`)  and where are they used in query?

Comment: 3 months before which date? 3 months before "fromdate", or 3 months before "todate". Or do you want to return all the months between the 2 dates? It's not very clear what you are expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using passing parameters in your query i.e `@fromdate` and `@todate` not used in your query, Use this parameters in where clause as below

```
select DATENAME(MONTH,tblReg.StartDate) AS [Month]
from tblReg
where
tblReg.StartDate>=DATEADD(MONTH,-3, @fromdate)
AND tblReg.EndDate<= @todate
GROUP BY 
DATENAME(MONTH,tblReg.StartDate)
```

Comment: i try this but this also april month Month
April
December
January
November
October

Comment: I am pretty sure about where condition this will gives last three month data, can you verify the passing date formats of both parameters

Comment: datetime is the type

Comment: No I am asking for Date Format `YYYY/MM/DD` like

Comment: oh that is yyyy/dd/mm 00:00:000 23:59:59

Comment: format '2016-07-01 00:00:00' , '2016-07-30 23:59:59' @JaydipJ

Comment: @user6628729 if you are passing this from date as ` '2016-07-01 00:00:00'`, then after subtracting 3 months this will gives you   `2016-04-01 00:00:00.000` i.e month April data as well